# "font-family: Emoji" screws up font spacing

Tags: arch-linux, firefox, fonts, apple

I was using apple music on linux for the first time, and I realized the font looked horrible and the text was way too spaced out.

Here's what it *should* look like:

```
It should look like this
```

but for some reason, it looks like:

```
this   for   some   reason
```

and it has to do with the fact that one of the fonts has the word "Emoji" in it, which causes the space between words to increase. I am on Arch Linux and I have tested this on Firefox and Chromium.
Here is a screenshot:
[image]

here's a minimalist version that produces this font rendering issue:

```html
<p style='font-family: "Emoji";'>This is too wide</p>
```